# Interrupt handle is not called after added with g_unix_signal_add

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer, glib

I am learning about gstreamer and I have a simple program where I want to end a stream gracefully after pressing CTRL+C in Linux. For this, I've read the source code for gst-launch and saw that g_unix_signal_add() is used for adding the signals. In my code I've added the line:

```
signal_watch_intr_id = g_unix_signal_add (SIGINT,
                       (GSourceFunc) intr_handler, data.pipeline);
```

where data is a structure containing the pipeline. My handling function is:

```
static gboolean
intr_handler (gpointer user_data)
{
  printf("handling interrupt.\n");
  GstElement *pipeline = (GstElement *) user_data;


  /* post an application specific message */
  gst_element_post_message (GST_ELEMENT (pipeline),
      gst_message_new_application (GST_OBJECT (pipeline),
          gst_structure_new ("GstLaunchInterrupt",
              "message", G_TYPE_STRING, "Pipeline interrupted", NULL)));

  /* remove signal handler */
  signal_watch_intr_id = 0;
  return G_SOURCE_REMOVE;
}
```

I expect it to print "handling interrupt." to the console, make the pipeline send a GST_MESSAGE_APPLICATION type message which then will be handled to stop the pipeline. However, the application simply does nothing after a SIGINT now. Because it does NOTHING, I know it changes the default handle, but I don't understand why it does not call the handling function. Can someone help me do this handling?

Comment: Please note that `printf` is not a [signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) function to call.

Comment: Not only `printf()`, but also all of of `gst_element_post_message()`, `gst_message_new_application()`, or `gst_structure_new()` are quite likely very, very, very async-signal-**unsafe**, meaning you're deep into undefined behavior.

Comment: May I ask then why the gst-launch-1.0 which is included in gstreamer library uses the gst_element_post_message for this? I am not experienced in signal handling and I'm genuinely curious why they used it what should be used

Comment: Signal handlers installed with `g_unix_signal_add()` are *not* libc signal handlers, so you don’t need to worry about only using async-signal-safe functions in them. Very roughly, the way `g_unix_signal_add()` works is to install a libc signal handler which sets a flag, and that flag is picked up in the next iteration of the `GMainContext`, and *that* is when your callback function is invoked.

Comment: So I suspect this isn’t working because you aren’t running a `GMainLoop` (or, equivalently, iterating a `GMainContext`). Is that the case?

Comment: @PhilipWithnall No, I'm not. I'm listening to the gstreamer bus for messages, but I know through Gstreamer Debug that nothing is posted on the bus, although it wakes up after SIGINT. 
gst-launch does not use GMainLoop either, but has an eventloop function where it adds the signal handler. It also uses a different function to get the messages (gst_bus_poll instead of gst_bus_timed_pop).

Comment: `gst_bus_poll()` is documented as running a main loop on the default `GMainContext` while it’s polling. Why are you using `gst_bus_timed_pop()` instead of `gst_bus_poll()`?

Comment: @PhilipWithnall Because it literally says "You should never use this function, since it is pure evil" in the GstBus documentation.

Comment: I missed that bit (I’m a GLib expert, not a GStreamer expert). My original answer still stands: in order to use `g_unix_signal_add()`, you need a main loop to be running. If you don’t have a main loop running, you won’t get signal callbacks.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall Ok, I understand now. I managed to it by adding a main loop. Will add an answer now. Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Philip's comments suggested, the problem was that I wasn't running a main loop and using gst_bus_timed_pop() to get the messages from the bus. By using a GMainLoop and adding a bus watcher(using gst_bus_add_watch) with a bus callback function, I managed to catch the interrupt as I wanted to.